Unknown supported Database Oracle 19.0
I am getting an issue with flyway and Oracle (Oracle Databse verion 19.21) in my Springboot application.
Versions:
flyway-core: 10.11.0
flyway-database-oracle: 10.11.0
spring-boot: 3.2.4
ojdbc11: 23.3.0.23.09

When I run the application I get the following:
Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception with message: Unsupported Database: Oracle 19.0
Complete Stacktrace:
{"level":"ERROR","message":"Application run failed","timestamp":"2024-04-22T07:16:15.197+0200",
"logger":"o.s.boot.SpringApplication","context":"abc.service","throwable_class":"BeanCreationException","throwable_root_cause_class":
"FlywayException","stack_hash":"345a5cc5","stack_trace":"o.f.c.a.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Oracle 19.0\n\tat 
o.f.c.i.d.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForConnection(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:105)\n\tat 
o.f.c.a.c.ClassicConfiguration.setDataSource(ClassicConfiguration.java:1095)\n\tat o.f.c.a.c.FluentConfiguration.dataSource(FluentConfiguration.java:624)\n\tat 
o.s.b.a.f.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureDataSource(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:185)\n\tat 
o.s.b.a.f.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:172)\n\tat 
j.i.r.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)\n\tat 
j.i.r.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat 
j.i.r.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat 
j.l.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat 
o.s.b.f.s.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)\n\t... 29 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: 
o.s.b.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' 
threw exception with message: Unsupported Database: Oracle 19.0\n\tat 
o.s.b.f.s.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)\n\tat 
o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)\n\t... 28 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: o.s.b.f.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource 
            
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 
Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception with message: 
Unsupported Database: Oracle 19.0\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolve r.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)\n\tat 
 o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)\n\tat 
 o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)\n\tat 
o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBe...\n"}

Thanks in advance!

Do you have your build script?

It looks like a compatibility issue between your spring-boot version and flyway version.

Thanks for a quick reply. Can you recommend the versions?

Below post might be helpful for you to resolve your compatibility issue.
https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/90196/integrating-flyway-with-my-spring-boot-java-application-unsupported-oracle-version-12-2

I have gone back to Spring recommended Dependencies but the problem remained the same. I have also added the tablespace Property to fly config, didn't help as well.

I removed flyway-core from the project and left just flyway-databa-oracle 9.22.3 for spring boot 3.2.3.
'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-database-oracle:9.22.3'

